# Update SQL Server table with XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

I have an XML variable that looks like this:

```
<code>
<IDs>
    <ID id="1">a</ID>
    <ID id="43">d</ID>
    <ID id="3">b</ID>

</IDs>
</code>
```

I want to use that in a stored procedure (SQL Server) that will update a table.

My table look like this:

```
ID INT,
a INT,
b INT,
c INT,
d INT
```

The statement should increase the letter value associated with the id.

SO it would look like this:

```
Table Row with ID = 1, update column "a" by increasing the current value by 1.
Table Row with ID = 43 - update column "d" by increasing current value by 1.
Finally Table row with ID= 3 - update column "b" by increasing value by 1.
```

This is what I have so far - (The second line is where i need the most help.):

```
Update MyTable
SET @letter = letterVal +1
WHERE ID IN(
SELECT x.v.value('@id','INT')
FROM @xmlIDs.nodes('/IDs/ID') x(v)
)
```

Comment: Do you say **SQL** (Structured Query Language), but you really mean **SQL Server** by that??

Comment: This... is awkwardly designed.  Do you have any ability to change the shape of the data at this point?

Comment: Yes SQL Server.  And yes I can redesign as necessary.  All that I really want to do is to count the number of each different letter.  I actually have an exam.  Each question in the exam has an id.  I want to count how many people answer a or b, etc. for each question.  I was hoping to do this with a single stored procedure instead of calling the same procedure for each question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to do something along the lines of this:

```
DECLARE @input XML = '<code>
<IDs>
    <ID id="1">a</ID>
    <ID id="43">d</ID>
    <ID id="3">b</ID>

</IDs>
</code>'

;WITH ParsedXML AS
(
SELECT
    ID = C.value('(@id)[1]', 'int'),
    ColumnName = C.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(10)')
FROM @Input.nodes('/code/IDs/ID') AS T(C)
)
UPDATE MyTable 
SET a = CASE WHEN p.ColumnName = 'a' THEN t.a + 1 ELSE t.a END,
    b = CASE WHEN p.ColumnName = 'b' THEN t.b + 1 ELSE t.b END,
    c = CASE WHEN p.ColumnName = 'c' THEN t.c + 1 ELSE t.c END,
    d = CASE WHEN p.ColumnName = 'd' THEN t.d + 1 ELSE t.d END
FROM MyTable t
INNER JOIN ParsedXml p ON t.ID = p.ID

SELECT * FROM Mytable
```

This will do it - but it's really quite ugly. The main problem is: you cannot get the column name as a value from somewhere else, to use it in the `UPDATE` statement - unless you go the dynamic SQL route, which has its own set of pros and cons and can get rather messy.

If you're interested in dynamic SQL - [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) by Erland Sommarskog is an **absolute must-read** - read it **before** you launch into using dynamic SQL!

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for!  Do you think that it would be better to have 4 different procedures (each updating a different letter) and then in my c# code loop through and choose the right procedure at that time?

Comment: @JustinPeterson: if it's just those four columns - you can definitely use this code. It's not very slick or pretty - but it works. If you'll get into a lot more "choices", then maybe you need to split it up to handle those separately

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you change your XML to resemble this:

```
<questions>
    <question id="1" answer="a" />
    <question id="43" answer="d" />
    <question id="3" answer="b" />
</questions>
```

With this format, you can write a query like so:

```
with CTE as (
    select
         x.n.value('@answer', 'char(1)') as answer
    from
        @Input.nodes('//questions/question') as x(n)
)
select 
    answer,
    count(answer) as answerCount
from
    CTE
group by
    answer;
```

You can then add these to a table as necessary, but the table you designed doesn't look like it would be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

One dynamic SQL solution.  Not too pretty but totally dynamic:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmp
GO
CREATE TABLE #tmp ( ID INT, a INT, b INT, c INT, d INT )
GO

INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES
    ( 1, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL ),
    ( 43, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0 ),
    ( 3, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL )
GO

SELECT 'before' s, * FROM #tmp

DECLARE @xml XML

SET @xml = '<code>
  <IDs>
    <ID id="1">a</ID>
    <ID id="43">d</ID>
    <ID id="3">b</ID>
  </IDs>
</code>'


-- Run a cursor through the XML resultset to update the table
DECLARE update_cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD LOCAL FOR 
SELECT
    x.y.value('@id', 'INT') id,
    x.y.value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)') columnName
FROM @xml.nodes('code/IDs/ID') AS x(y)

-- Cursor variables
DECLARE @id INT, @columnName VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

OPEN update_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM update_cursor INTO @id, @columnName
WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIN

    --SELECT @id, @columnName

    SET @sql = 'UPDATE #tmp SET ' + @columnName + ' += 1 WHERE ID = ' + CAST( @id AS VARCHAR(20) )

    EXEC(@sql)
    --SELECT @sql

    FETCH NEXT FROM update_cursor INTO @id, @columnName
END

CLOSE update_cursor
DEALLOCATE update_cursor
GO

SELECT 'after' s, * FROM #tmp
```